# Confusion about template retrieval in single page apps and the difference with typical file retrievals

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, angularjs, express

I have a conceptual uncertainty about the way AngularJS deals with single page routing, and whether that's at all similar to the way typical css/javascripts files are retrieved from the server.

Suppose I have the following sources in my rendered html file:

```
/javascripts/client.js
/css/main.css
```

I never had to listen for them on my server (in Express, like this):

```
app.get('/:dir/:name',function(req,res){
 if (req.params.dir == 'javascripts){
  //render the client.js
  //....
  //render the main.css
 })
```

Express knew where to look for them, and retrieved them behind my back. Even if I try listening for those, for some reason I was never able to catch them when they come.

On the other hand, when I create a route in AngularJS that looks like this:

```
.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/write',{templateUrl: '/templates/mainpage'})  
});
```

I have to listen for it on my back-end and retrieve it by hand. I have to write this:

```
app.get('/templates/:name',function(req,res){
 res.render('templates/'+req.params.name');
});
```

How can I make sense of this difference?

I appreciate any light!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express doesn't do anything behind your back. Express knows where to look for those static files because you told express where too look for them by defining:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Don't do this:

```
app.get('/templates/:name',function(req,res){
 res.render('templates/'+req.params.name');
});
```

Create static html templates and put them into the public folder. Express will serve them.
Populate the templates with json data from the server.

You are mixing express views and angularjs templates. Both are designed for different use.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to work on it right now (the jade is a little messy). Is there a reason that rendering a static file and then retrieving the data via json is preferable to rendering a dynamic file?

Comment: Simply put the reason is performance. You don't need to render static content on every request. I don't know what you are doing in your templates and how you fill those templates in angular.